# Automate SQL Server 2008 backup script failing to run

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, permissions, scripting

I have created a maintenance plan but when I try to execute I get the error:

```
Message
[298] SQLServer Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'XX\Administrator', error code 0x534. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin)
```

I have given administrator db owner access but still get the error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when this happens you just need to edit the job and save it again.  This will "usually" fix the problem.

Failing that try changing it to run under a SQL Account such as the sa account so that it doesn't need to check for domain credentials before running the job.

Answer (score 6):

i had this problem and had to change the owner on the job to and sql account with the necessary permissions - > under SQL Agent > right click the job associated with your maintenance plan > Properties > Owner

If you later change the Maintenance plan the job owner changes back to your login so you have to go through this again.

Comment: I had the same issue. An admin that left the company created these maintenance plans. Even though we disabled the account (in AD), we had no issues coming up. However, when we finally deleted the account (in AD) the Maintenance jobs started to fail. Don't ask me how SQL server can run a job with a disabled user (the user was not disabled in SQL server security but in AD).

Answer (score 1):

Those maintenance plans need correct permissions for the account trying to run the maintenance jobs.

check the owner in Maintenance Plan job - in SQL Agent jobs. Try using the "sa" just to check if it works with this user, then you can change to the user you need.

This error usually occurs in Active Directory setup.  Do you have it installed? Perhaps, your SQL Server service is running as a local account and it does not have domain access. Also check SQL Server Configuration Manager for SQL Server Agent account. Does it have necessary rights?

Some answers are here: http://www.windows-tech.info/15/944bdabc733a57e3.php

Answer (score 1):

The Maintenance Plans use the SQLAgent service to lookup the NT account info.   If your on Vista or Windows7, personally, I would restart the SQL server running as the proper user account.   Also, SP3 of SQL 2005 asks for you to explicitly define authority for certain user accounts as the admin of the SQL Server.   If you didn't get that right then you might get problems with that.   Did you put service pack 3 on your SQL 2005 yet?

Here is a screenshot of it:
[alt text http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/mnielsen/clip_image064_3B215F37.jpg](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/mnielsen/clip_image064_3B215F37.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . Maintaiance plan was giving me error . For this Go to SQL server Agent (Right Click) click on Jobs -> click on the relevent sub plan - > change the owner of the database to [sa]. and now execute the maintainance plan